# Modifying IIS Recycle period restarts timer?

Tags: iis

My IIS is set to recycle after a specific elapsed time.

What happens when I change this setting? Is the internal IIS timer resets, or does it continue from the same point in time?

For example, the app pool was set to recycle every 30 hours. 15 hours after the last recycle I modify it to recycle every 25 hours.

When will be its next recycle - after 25 hours or after 10 hours (25-15)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Application pools can be recycled by configuration changes; however, I would hope that changing the app pool setting for recycle time would not trigger a recycle (unless the time had elapsed). Therefore, I would guess 10 hours. The best way to find out would probably be to turn on event logging on recycle. I don't know which version of IIS you are running - but here are instruction on enabling event logging for the app pool for IIS 7.0; the instructions should still apply for later versions: http://blogs.iis.net/ganekar/iis-7-0-application-pool-recycles-log-a-event-in-windows-event-log

Comment: This does not answer the question. You should pose questions and make diagnostic suggestions as comments. Also, SF generally frowns on "chatty" stuff like "I would hope ..." and "I would guess" as opposed to simply well reasoned and supported _answers_.